ABP Framework Custom Headers for Data Filtering
I am currently exploring ABP Framework to develop a web application and I am in need to have a filter in the Data Context. I want the user to set a specific Location to filter data around but want that to be global to all queries. I would like to have a custom header added to the requests coming from blazor wasm project that will be captured by the httpaccessor and then added to the filter in the db context. The problem that I have is that haven't found a way to override or inject a custom header to each request coming from BlazorWASM. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to add those headers or be able to access the underlying httpClient that is used on Blazor WASM?
